# Decoding bitmap from Drawable Resource Id is giving null

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I want to get Bitmap from drawable resource id, I found a solution to decode it using BitmapFactory decode method, but it's giving null.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_tick);
```

Comment: What type of file is `ic_tick`, exactly?

Comment: I created it from Android Studio using File -> New -> Vector Asset

Comment: so it is **not** a bitmap file like `.png`, `.jpg` etc - you can use `BitmapFactory` only with those bitmap files

Comment: this issue is solved i was using vector drawable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check if you are using Vector drawable or normal png/jpeg image as a drawable, it gives null value if you try to decode vector drawable.

Use this code if you are trying to decode Vector drawable

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
}

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
        drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);

return bitmap;
}
```

Also make sure if you have vector support enable in your app gradle

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: You saved my day,
I created it from Android Studio using File -> New -> Vector Asset
So this was a Vector Drawable